# A variable name represents / expresses / indicates something?

Tags: verbs, comparison

```
string GetFieldValue(string fieldName){}
```

It's our old code to retrieve data from a database table, but it can't return NULL. An empty string and a null are different. So I made some change,

```
struct StringCanBeNULL {
    string sValue;
    bool bNull;
}
StringCanBeNULL GetFieldValue(string fieldName){}
```

I'm writing some comments for StringCanBeNULL.

sValue means the old db value. bNull indicates if the value is null.

Should I use

```
sValue represents the db value. 
sValue expresses the db value. sValue
sValue indicates the db value.
```

which of them?

Comment: WHy not just "sValue is the db value"  Or better Rename the variable to sDbValue, so you don't need the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already stated, 'sValue' is the *name* of a variable.

We wouldn't normally say that a name represents, expresses, or indicates something. A name *identifies* someone or something specific.

I think you should just say:

> sValue **is** the db value.